# Weird bit shifting behaviour

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I was attempting the powerset problem with iteration and bit shifting.
There is a particular behaviour I am unable to comprehend.
I would have expected all the 3 statement below to indicate testing if jth bit in i is set.
Why are the results different then?

```
private static void printSubsetInBit(Integer[] arr) {
                for(int i=0;i<(1<<arr.length);i++){
                    List<Integer> pack=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
                        //if(((i>>j)&1)==1){ -->>>> WORKS
                        //if((i & ( 1<<j))>0){-->>>> WORKS
                        if((i & ( 1<<j))==1){ -->>>> DOES NOT WORK
                            pack.add(arr[j]);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(pack.toString());
                }
        }
```

Comment: `(i & ( 1<<j))==1` is false, unless `j == 0`, because then `(1<<j) & 1 == 0`.

Comment: Instead of `==1` replace it with `!=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you left-shift 1 by j and then use it to mask i, you have to compare the result to the result of left-shifting 1 by j, not to 1.

In other words the condition should be

```
((i & (1 << j)) == (1 << j))
```

Or just "!= 0" would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

`(i & ( 1<<j))==1` is false unless `j == 0`, because `((1<<j) & 1 == 0) == (j != 0)` (*).

This is simply not equivalent to the other expressions.

---

(*) Well, `j % 32 == 0`/`j % 32 != 0`; the second operand is masked.

Comment: I'm sorry, but bit shifts don't wrap around. Bits shifted out are simply lost.

Comment: The JLS says, "The value of n << s is n left-shifted s bit positions; this is equivalent (even if overflow occurs) to multiplication by two to the power s.
The value of n >> s is n right-shifted s bit positions with sign-extension. The resulting value is floor(n / 2s). For non-negative values of n, this is equivalent to truncating integer division, as computed by the integer division operator /, by two to the power s.
The value of n >>> s is n right-shifted s bit positions with zero-extension". So, yeah, I'm sure.

Comment: @LewBloch so does ideone run a non-compliant version of Java?

Comment: Your reference doesn't show that bits wrap around as a result of a shift.

Comment: Does the JLS fail to authoritatively describe Java's syntax and semantics?

Comment: You seem to be describing the masking of the second operand, not bit wrapping.

Comment: @LewBloch ok, I was using the wrong terminology. Updated.